# knitr::spin doesn't always add a line break to ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I tried to reproduce this using dummy data but was not able to, however I'll try my best to incorporate the details from production data that cannot be shared.

I am trying to knit an Rmd file to md using knitr::spin() (specifically, using the ezknitr wrapper).

Sometimes multiple ggplots have a linebreak, but other times they do not, resulting in large plots that go off the page.

I am not sure why some plots are on different lines, and others are not in the resulting .md output.

Here's an example .md output:

```
some text................................

other text............................................

![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-3](reports/figs/unnamed-chunk-3-1.png)![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-3](reports/figs/unnamed-chunk-3-2.png)![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-3](reports/figs/unnamed-chunk-3-3.png)![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-3](reports/figs/unnamed-chunk-3-4.png)


![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-4](reports/figs/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png)
```

and the code used to generate this md:

````
some text................................

other text............................................

```{r}
ca <- filter(sv.cal, role %in% c("CA", "CAEX", "CABS")) %>%
  select(emp_id, region, total_sales = ann.sales)

ca2 <- filter(sv.cal, role %in% c("CA", "CAEX", "CABS"), total_sales > 0) %>%
  select(emp_id, region, total_sales = ann.sales)


g <- ggplot(data=ca, aes(x=total_sales / 1000 )) +
  geom_freqpoly(bins=20, aes(color = region)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1e03)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 150)) + 
  labs(x = "Total Sales by CAs $M", y = "Count of CAs", title = "No significant differentiation in sales by CAs along Region/MGO")
g  

ggplot(data=ca2, aes(region, total_sales)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar) + 
  labs(x = "Region", y = "$M") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,2000000))


bai <- filter(sv.total, role %in% c("BAI")) %>%
  mutate(ann.sales = annualize(total_sales, nmonth))

ggplot(data=bai, aes(region, ann.sales / 1e06)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) + 
  labs(x = "Region", y = "$MM") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,20))

ggsave(file = "img/bai_performance.png", scale = 2)
ca_percentile <- ca %>%
  group_by(region, emp_id) %>%
  summarise(total_sales = sum(total_sales)) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  crossing(p = seq(.1, .9, .1)) %>%
  mutate(q = quantile(total_sales, p)) %>%
  select(-total_sales) %>%
  select(-emp_id) %>%
  distinct(region, p, .keep_all = TRUE)

ggplot(data=ca_percentile, aes(p, q, colour = region)) +
  geom_line() + 
  labs( x = "Percentile", y = "Sales Volume $", title = "Distribution of Sales by Region for CAs shows no material change between CA performance across regions") + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar)
ggsave(file = "img/ca_performance_quantile.png", scale = 2)

```
````

Comment: That's what `knit` does, not `spin`. You need to add enough data and code to make this reproducible to get a useful answer.

Comment: I tried to create a reproducible example by faking the data and keeping as much of the ggplot / dplyr language intact, but in doing so, the problem disappeared. I managed a workaround by wrapping individual ggplots into their own r chunk. In doing so, the plots are now on their own line and no longer appear side-by-side.

Comment: I found the answer, someone had a similar issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/haYUph5jj6g

Specifically, the problem is a bug with spin() that doesn't work well with ggsave. No real solution is given.